# Logstash mutate gsub for s3 special characters

Tags: amazon-s3, logstash

I'm trying to upload a file from Logstash to s3. Therefore, I want to replace all [special characters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) in the field that will be the s3 key.

The filter that I'm using in my conf:

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "log.file.path", "[=@&<>{}:,~#`%\;\$\+\?\\\^\[\]\|\s+]", "_" ]

  }
}
```

I also added an output to file to test the gsub :

```
output {
  file {
     codec => rubydebug
     path => "/tmp/test_gsub"
  }
  s3 {
   ....
 }
}
```

An example of output in /tmp/test_gsub that shows that the gsub didn't work:

```
"@timestamp" => 2020 - 06 - 04T08: 40: 17.564Z,
"log" => {
    "offset" => 1784971,
    "file" => {
        "path" => "/var/log/AVI1:VM_B30/app.log"
    }
},
"message" => "just random message",
```

The log.file.path still has the `:` in the path. I would expect the path to change to `/var/log/AVI1_VM_B30/app.log`

### Update

Tried also to use the following regex but still got same result :

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "log.file.path", "[:]", "_" ]

  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @JeyJ, have you tried to do the mutate on `path` only, without the `log.file`? I think logstash treat fields as their key, without the full "path" to the field name.

Comment: I will try and update in a sec

Comment: @eladyanai same result unfortunately.

Comment: Hey @JeyJ, I have tested your regex and it seems to be working. i will try to check another option for you.

Comment: @eladyanai I checked also the regex online, but it seems that the gsub doesnt work even if I use only the : char. (Check the post I edited it with an example).

Comment: "path" is a reserved logstash field, maybe it is being calculated after the gsub and is overriding it. can you try doing the same on another field maybe? copy path into let say "tpath" and then run the gsub on tpath?

Comment: sure, will update in a sec

Comment: @eladyanai - thanks for the help but I found the right solution.

Comment: No worries, I am glad it worked out! @JeyJ.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me in the end :

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [ "[log][file][path]", "[=@&<>{}:,~#`%\;\$\+\?\\\^\[\]\|\s+]", "_" ]

  }
```